# Microsoft Graph: Unable to filter by binary singleValueExtendedProperty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to retrieve an event from the grapi api based on a binary extended property that I already have a value for. I have retrieved this value from the same api so I know that an event with this value exists. I also know that the property id is correct since I used this with .Expand() to get the value.

```
var value = "BAAAAIIA4AB0xbcQGoLgCAAAAAAwMvfBFvzUAQAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAEZ53uCfQ51AhtRf+FNQjOk=";
var cleanGlobalObjectIdPropertyId = "Binary {6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305} Id 0x23";

var events = await client.Users["myuser@example.com"].Events.Request()
    .Filter($"singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{cleanGlobalObjectIdPropertyId}' and ep/value eq '{value}')")
    .GetAsync();
```

This is the error i get:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter
>
> Message: The filter expression for $filter does not match to a single extended property and a value restriction.

I have used the same filter syntax with an extended property of type string and that works fine, so I think the fact that this is a binary property is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Getting the same error on similar query. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Is it even possible to msearch against binary singleValueExtendedProperties?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced to this problem. But I try to search for /messages against mapi property SearchKey. 
I was thinking to use something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2Fid%20eq%20'Binary%200x300B'%20and%20ep%2Fvalue%20eq%20'yxum+DwfxUy13C4qs5R6ig==')
```

According to https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358

"The six comparison operators can be used with all primitive values except Edm.Binary, Edm.Stream, and the Edm.Geo types."

So I assume that binary should be casted or decoded from base64 somehow, or it's impossible at all.

UPDATE:
So I finally figure it out.
Let's say I got the value of singleValueExtendedProperty as:

```
{
    "id": "Binary 0x300b",
    "value": "yxum+DwfxUy13C4qs5R6ig=="
}
```

And I wanted to find message by value of this property.  The problem here is that '+' should be encoded if exists. Also value should be casted to Edm.Binary.  Correct query looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties%2FAny(ep%3A%20ep%2Fid%20eq%20'Binary%200x300B'%20and%20cast(%20ep%2Fvalue,Edm.Binary)%20eq%20binary'yxum%2BDwfxUy13C4qs5R6ig==')
```