# Microsoft Graph: Unable to filter by binary singleValueExtendedProperty on events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Why is it possible to run this query:

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'Binary 0x300B' and cast( ep/value,Edm.Binary) eq binary'yx==')
```

against messages and contacts, but not against events?:

Example:

```
GET /v1.0/me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'Binary 0x300B' and cast( ep/value,Edm.Binary) eq binary'yx==')
```

which gives the answer: ErrorRestrictionTooComplex

Like this question: [Microsoft Graph: Unable to filter by binary singleValueExtendedProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55863793/4333910) it was once possible.